# Why does `this` keyword refer to Window not Component in React onClick() method

Tags: meteor, reactjs

I thought it was the case that the `this` keyword always refers to the component in React, but in my `toggleStyle` method in the below `this` is returning the window object instead of the React component object .  Can somebody help me to understand why that is?

```
renderDeviceToggle() {

    var arrowAnimation = {
        rotateX: this.state.expanded ? 180 : 0,
        transformOriginY: [ '42%', '42%' ]
    };

    let toggleState = function () {
        // 'this' is the window
        console.log("in toggleState: this: ", this)
        this.setState({expanded: !this.state.expanded});
    };

    return (
        <div className="device-toggle" onClick={toggleState}>
            <div>{console.log("in return: this is the component: ", this)}</div>
            <div className="device-icon icon huge"></div>
            <VelocityComponent duration={300} animation={arrowAnimation}>
                <div className="icon color-blue flex">
                    <i className="icon-caret-down"></i>Hi
                </div>
            </VelocityComponent>
        </div>
    );
},

render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <div className="panel panel-default">
                <div className="panel-heading">
                    <div className="pull-right text-right">
                        <p><a href="/addOrder" className="pull-right">New order </a></p>
                        <p><a href="#"> View all</a></p>
                    </div>
                    <h4>Top orders</h4>
                </div>
                <div className="panel-body">
                    { this.data.orders ?
                        this.renderOrderTable() :
                        <p>Loading</p> }
                </div>
                <div>
                    {this.renderDeviceToggle()}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason this is happening is because React only binds the top level functions in your class to 'this'. So in this case both `render` and `renderDeviceToggle` are bound as you would expect. However, inside `renderDeviceToggle` you have created a new function,`toggleState`, that React doesn't know about. Therefore, this code works under the normal javascript rules when a function is created.

As mentioned in another answer, to solve you would need to use the arrow context or explicitly bind the new function to 'this'.

Answer (score 4):

You can use arrow functions to get lexically bound `this`:

```
let toggleState = () => {
    // 'this' should be the component
    console.log("in toggleState: this: ", this)
    this.setState({expanded: !this.state.expanded});
};
```

Or explicitly `bind` the context:

```
let toggleState = function () {
    // 'this' should be the component
    console.log("in toggleState: this: ", this)
    this.setState({expanded: !this.state.expanded});
}.bind(this);
```

As to the *how* and *why* `this` works in JS here's a great explanation https://stackoverflow.com/a/3127440/4879